# WinForms Title Bar Text Not Showing Up in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, desktop-application

My WinForms application shows the title bar text in the designer but does not show it in runtime. I suspect it is some sort of parameter that is incorrectly set.

[Design Time Title Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAc3S.png)

[Runtime title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PJAp.png)

I attempted to Change the Form's ForeColor, font, and name which correspond to the default font color, font and title bar text respectively. None of these parameter changes solved the problem

Also attempted to change the Windows 10 Accent color in the OS settings. Did not work.

I made a huge mistake by not simply building my app in WinUI, and I'm in too deep to port it over. I can provide more details if necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Caption (Title Bar) is non-client area. That's drawn by the desktop window manager. Changing properties as ForeColor and Font only affects the ClientArea and the child Controls that inherit them from the Parent. Since that's not the default colorization, check your System settings again

Comment: Open VS, create a new WinForms app. Press F5. Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: @Flydog57 The problem does not present itself in a new WinForms App. I checked my code for this.Text changes but there are none.

Comment: So, it's something you did.  Do you use source control (if you don't, consider using Git)? If all else fails, consider starting a new project and moving your code over bit by bit. It often goes a lot faster than you expect (been there, done thst)

Comment: @Flydog57, I don't currently have any source control on my project sadly. It's a standalone solo project so I didn't think it would be necessary. I am learning new things every day.

If what Jimi said is true, I shouldn't have been able to create this problem at all.

Comment: You can try diff-ing your plain test project with your messed up on (the form .cs file and the designer file) failing that try moving your working functionality over from your messed up project to a new on. It's not an OS setting, it's something you coded

Comment: @Flydog57 The diff didn't show anything significant, but I was able to move my Form.cs, FormDesigner.cs, and ansillary classes over to a fresh winforms application. After gutting all the nuget package-specific functionality and event handlers I was able to get the title bar to appear!

I now wonder if the problem has something to do with a NuGet package or something else... The search continues.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes something deep in the bowels of the designer (or other magic code) messes up, and all you can do is get a shovel out and clean up. Consider looking into using local source control (like Git)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
I had this block of code hidden in one of my partial classes:

> public override string Text { get; set; }

It appears to have overridden the Text attribute of the form

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).